# Нужно сравнить список слов со словами из текста

Tags: python, текст, сравнение

Есть список слов:

```
keywords = ['карт', 'card', 'cvv', 'код', 'code', 'bank']
```

Нужно написать  функцию которая выявляет что встречается ли эти слова в тексте: Привет, держи данные от моей карты: Elon Musk 08/26, и на результате выдает True

Answer (score 1):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! В следующий раз старайтесь предоставлять свои попытки решения!

```
keywords = ['карт', 'card', 'cvv', 'код', 'code', 'bank']
line = 'Привет, держи данные от моей карты: Elon Musk 08/26'

for i in keywords:
    if i in line:
        print("True")
```

Comment: `for j in line:` все же надо сравнивать слова и слова, а не слова и символы

Comment: @deethereal да, спасибо, что подметили, очень глупая ошибка.

Comment: 'карт' в keywords  и карты в line разные ту скорее нужно искать вхождения слов в предложений

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто помогал в этом вопросе! Я нашел решение уже сам, оно кривое, понимаю, но выдает правильный ответ.

```
def findkeywords(message):
    keywords = ['карт', 'card', 'cvv', 'код', 'code', 'bank']
    message.text = ('Привет, держи данные от моей карты: Elon Musk 08/26')
    for n in keywords:
        k = message.text.find(n)
        if k >= 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Использовал функцию find(), которое возвращает индекс на котором начинается слово, и если он не находит то возвращает -1. Спасибо всем

Comment: Вы дали ответ и если  он вас не устраивает, то или удалите его, или задайте новый вопрос.